# arch create EFI partition -- invalid token EFI System Partition

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, parted

I'm following instructions given here for creation of EFI partition:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Parted

But my installation is not behaving according to the description

```
 (parted) print
 Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
 Sector Size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: msdos
 Disk Flags
```

When I attempt to create the partition

```
 (parted) mkpart "EFI System Partion" fat32 1MiB 261 MiB
 parted: invalid token: EFI System partition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a disk with an old MSDOS partitioning scheme: *Partition Table: msdos*

Please run `mklabel gpt` first.